# In sql table I want to store data of appointment 'pa_date' is this format 'dd-MM-yyyy : hh:mm tt'.D ata type is 'datetime', how should I convert it

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
create table patientAppointment
(
    pa_id bigint not null identity primary key,
    pa_date datetime not null,
    pa_turnNumber smallint not null,
    pa_status tinyint not null
)
```

Comment: To answer the question in the Title (put your question in the question, not just random code): You don't. Date and Time values are stored as binary values. If you want the **display** the values in a particular format, then that's for your presentation layer to do, not the RDBMS.

Comment: Dates are not stored in a format.  They are stored by precision.  How precise do you need the datetime to be?  Down to the millisecond?  Only to the day?

Comment: If I'm inserting data through c# windows application and the date format is 'dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm tt' then what should I do to store it is that particular format .
Is there any function to convert it ?

Comment: *"then what should I do to store it is that particular format"*, as i said: "You don't." When your application passes the data, from the RDBMS, to the presentation layer, the presentation layer should have the format defined there.

Comment: As for passing the data, don't pass values in the format `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt`. As you're using C# pass the value as a sql datetime data type; not an ambiguous date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't want to do that.  You want to store the data using the *correct* data type, and that is `datetime` (or some variant such as `datetime2(0)`.

You can format it as a string for output.  In fact, you can add a computed column to do just that:

```
create table patientAppointment (
    pa_id bigint not null identity primary key,
    pa_date datetime not null,
    pa_turnNumber smallint not null,
    pa_status tinyint not null,
    pa_date_mmddyyyy as (convert(varchar(255), pa_date, 105) + ' ' + convert(varchar(255), convert(time, pa_date))))
);
```

`pa_date_mmddyyyy` has the value converted as a string, which can be used in queries.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are passing a string and NOT a datetime, you can simply convert it.

**Example**

```
Select AsDateTime = try_convert(datetime,'29-09-2020 1:30 PM',105)
```

**Returns**

```
AsDateTime
2020-09-29 13:30:00.000
```